# Which is faster using string or moving data to fixed fields

Tags: cobol

Traditionally, COBOL writes printed output by defining a data structure in the working storage composed of fields and fillers, then the code moves data to be printed to the fields using MOVE verb (variations exist on this of course).

A possible alternative is to use STRING verb to construct the output line record.

The platform which I am targeting is IBM ENTERPRISE COBOL and I currently have no access to it! The program is expected to run using millions of records and the decision is fundamental before the coding starts.  I am considering the STRING option since it is more flexible and may allow changing the print line format without changing the code in the future, this is a realistic possibility but not a concrete requirement.

**My question is:** I expect, but don't know for sure, that STRING takes significant CPU time. Would using STRING instead of MOVE cause a significant slow-down to the program (say more than 20%)?

I understand that the question is not very precise, and I don't expect anyone to have an exact answer unless that person has done a similar test, but maybe someone somewhere did a similar test and had a good guess based on that test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRING var DELIMITED BY SIZE into var-2` *must be* nearly as fast as a `MOVE` because it commonly goes down to the same CPU instructions. It could even be faster as a `STRING` doesn't do any type conversions, which `MOVE` does (and that is the one place where `MOVE` has "more power").

The more phrases you add to the `STRING` (which is of course in general the "more powerful" command) the more needs to be done at run-time so you get a slowdown, but then if you do the same on your own (like incrementing a position counter) it will be faster again to directly do this in one statement.

For performance it likely is more important what the code "around that" actually does, and "printing" sounds like file io (preferably file, possibly DB2) - and that is the place where you'll need to tweak for performance, not `MOVE` vs. `STRING` - just use what is most appropriate to get the task done - and watch out to use `USAGE DISPLAY` for variables that directly goes into "printing", and for counters and calculations the most appropriate `USAGE` (likely signed integers with `COMP`).

As always: the only way to ensure you get the best performance is actual *testing* **on the target machine**.

Comment: Excellent thoughts, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to overly optimize your source code to get better performance. IMHO, writing code that is easier to understand and to maintain is preferable over tricky code trying to improve performance by predicting what machine instructions will be used.

I'm not contradicting Simon's answer, just ammending it. Modern compilers do incredible magic when transforming the (COBOL) source statements into machine instructions. I'm especially talking about IBM's Enterprise COBOL for z/OS, because I have had some working experience with this one. Besides optimization levels, you also choose the target architecture level, i.e. the processor generation, that the code should be optimized for. Depending on those settings, completely different machine instruction sequences may be generated for the same source code. And this probably has much higher impact on runtime performance than using one code sequence over another.

I'm not implying choosing STRING versus MOVE is over-optimizing.

Comment: Nice thought, thank you.